# Using PHP Glob with Retina.js pulls all images including @2x

Tags: php, glob, retina.js

I'm using http://retinajs.com/ (Retina.js) for my portfolio site. Retina.js requires the @2x image to be placed within the same directory using the same file name and extension. For example, image01.jpg will be replaced with image01@2x.jpg when retina.js notices that a device is using a higher DPI.

My problem is that I'm also using the PHP glob function to retrieve all of the image files within a directory and display them on a page. This means that it also pulls the @2x image at the same time even on a normal 72 dpi screen. But the @2x image is only supposed to load on a screen with a higher DPI.

My simple PHP code is:

```
$files = glob('images/projects/'.$filename.'/*.{jpg}', GLOB_BRACE);

    foreach($files as $file) {

        echo '<img src="'.$file.'" title="'.$title.'" />';

    }
```

Is there any way of making retina.js and PHP glob work together? My aim to to pull all of the images within a directory except the @2x image for a normal 72dpi screen.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes it is possible to make these work together.  There are probably hundreds of ways to filter out those unwanted files from the directory.  What have you tried so far to do this?

Comment: Hi Mike, I did not want to touch the retina.js file due to my lack of experience. So I've been playing with PHP and realized that the filenames need to be exactly the same. So I can not do anything there. I was thinking of using PHP to filter out filenames using preg_match that exclude the '@2x'. But I am not sure whether this will affect the retina images. Also I can't check this on a normal 72 dpi screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way:

```
foreach($files as $file) {
    //check that the file doesn't have @2x in the name.
    if(strpos($file, '@2x')===false){
        echo '<img src="'.$file.'" title="'.$title.'" />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Holy gosh that was a fast response. Thank you Jonathan! I've just tested your code and it worked perfectly. I wasn't sure if this would affect the retina.js but it seems to remove the @2x image on a normal dpi screen. Thank again for your help, much appreciated! :)